# How can i display option values in a div without repeating it (javascript or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here and I wanna display the selected option in a `div` `id="iteminfo"` and I want to avoid displaying it multiple times when I select that same option. Please your assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $(".myactivity").click(function (event) {
             var total = 0;
             $(".myactivity option:checked").each(function () {
                 total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                 var iteminfo = $(this).text();
                 $("#iteminfo").append(iteminfo);
             });

             if (total == 0) {
                 $('#amount').val('');
             } else {
                 $('#amount').val(total);
             }
         });
     });
```

and here's my `div` id tag

```
<div class="form-control"> 
                    <label class="header">Summary <span>*</span></label>
                     <div id="iteminfo"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: you need to clear previously added values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $(".myactivity").click(function (event) {
             var total = 0;
             var iteminfo = [];
             $(".myactivity option:checked").each(function () {
                 total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                 iteminfo.push($(this).text());
             });

             $("#iteminfo").html(iteminfo.join('<br/>'));

             if (total == 0) {
                 $('#amount').val('');
             } else {
                 $('#amount').val(total);
             }
         });
     });
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: you can use `iteminfo += $(this).text();`

Comment: That's a great idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks guys for this. it helped. im now having an issue inserting a line break.

Comment: You can not line break when use set text. I will edit my code. Wait a minute.

Comment: @@Felix If it is helpful, you don't forget award.

Comment: @TienNguyen yeah sure